# Is there any possibility to change speed (make it slower) of androids indeterminate progressbar?

Tags: android, user-interface, progress-bar

The **speed** of my **indeterminate horizontal progressbar** is absolutely **too fast**.

My progressbar is showing while my application is loading (splashscreen).

Anybody an **idea** to **decrease** the **speed** of the moving bar? It looks totally stupid how it works at the moment.

**Thank you** in advance for your help and your ideas! :-)

Answer (score 5):

In your layout file, add this property android:indeterminateDuration

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prbSplashScreen"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateDuration="1000"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

If you want to increase the speed then increase this property. Decrease this property to slow down the progress bar.